# How to run an event after completely finish the previous event?

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with some jquery please see below code.

I have 2 events running. What I am trying to achieve is when the first event is completely finishes then I want to run second event.

First event

```
$("#brand div").each(function(e) {
$(this).delay(600*e).fadeTo('slow',1)
})
```

Second event

```
$(".b-circle-image a").each(function(ev) {
$(this).delay(600*ev).fadeTo('slow',1);
})
```

I even tried like this using `status = false;` but still doesn't work.

```
    var checkStatus  = true;
    $("#brand div").each(function(e) {//Display segments in order
      $(this).delay(600*e).fadeTo('slow',1)
      checkStatus = false;
    })
    if(!checkStatus==false){
      $(".b-circle-image").show();
      $(".b-circle-image a").each(function(ev) {//Display circle image in order
      $(this).delay(600*ev).fadeTo('slow',1);
    })
    }
```

If any one has any idea about this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// You can create deferred object for each fadeTo and resolve it on complete animation callback.
var firstEvent = $("#brand div").map(function(i, el) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    $(el).delay(600*i).fadeTo('slow', 0, function() {
        dfd.resolve();
    })
    return dfd;
});
// Then use $.when function (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)
$.when.apply(this, firstEvent).done(function() {
    $(".b-circle-image a").each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(600*i).fadeTo('slow',0);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

**First Event:**

```
return myFirstEvent();

function myFirstEvent() {

$("#brand div").each(function(e) {
$(this).delay(600*e).fadeTo('slow',1)
return mySecondEvent();
})

}
```

**Second Event:**

```
function mySecondEvent(){

$(".b-circle-image a").each(function(ev) {
$(this).delay(600*ev).fadeTo('slow',1);
})

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is a good idea but you need to set your status to `true` only when the each loop finishes with the last item. You can do something like this:

```
var $elms = $('div'),
    complete = false;

$elms.each(function (idx, value) {
    //...
    if (++idx === $elms.length) {
        complete = true;
    }
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into [`jQuery.Deferred()`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved with a jQuery deferred object:

```
// initialize the deferred object
var deferred = $.Deferred();

// queue your events
deferred.done(myFirstEvent, mySecondEvent);

// resolve the deferred object to trigger events
deferred.resolve();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var queue = [];
$("#brand div").each(function() {
    queue.push(
        function(i) {
            $(this).delay(600*i).fadeTo('slow',1)
        }.bind(this)
    );
});
$(".b-circle-image a").each(function(ev) {
    queue.push(
        function(i) {
            $(this).delay(600*i).fadeTo('slow',1)
        }.bind(this)
    );
});
queue.map(function(el, i) {
    el(i);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

This may accomplish the goal in a similar way to Jquery.Deferred() but, you could also try creating a wrapper function that utilises setTimeout() to delay the second event.

```
setTimeout(function() { function mySecondEvent(); }, 15);
```

**OR** you could try Jquery.Delay()

```
.delay( duration [, queueName] )
```

durationAn integer indicating the number of milliseconds to delay execution of the next item in the queue.

queueNameA string containing the name of the queue. Defaults to fx, the standard effects queue.

**More info here:** http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: You won't know when the previous event finishes so this way can't achieved exactly however only you can assume the time interval of first event and set time out.